# joedixon/laravel-translation not working during update

Tags: php, laravel, translation

For testing purpose I have Installed fresh Laravel-7 and also installed ***joedixon/laravel-translation*** package, all are working fine.
After that I have changed root directory and others (I have to change for implementing the **Translation** in another running project which root directory like that)-

Change things are-

1. Moved **index.php** into root directory, ex:  ***myproject/public/index.php*** to ***myproject/index.php***
2. Move **.htaccess** into root directory
3. In **index.php**, changed-
   ***require __ DIR __.'/vendor/autoload.php';*** 
   and
   ***$app = require_once __ DIR __.'/bootstrap/app.php';***
4. And for Translation I added the **/public/** for the path of css, js in ***resources/views/vendor/translation/layout.blade.php***

And now all are working but when I try to update the translation file, It throws an error showing the requested url is not found.
Everything else seems to work fine expect for updating the translations. 
How to solve  ?

Screenshot attached. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5L5f.png)

Answer (score 0):

i didnt work with this package before but i have noticied a double slash `//` in your requested url you trying to post to ( in the screenshot ) so that could cause a 404 since there is difference between

`http://localhost/cartpro_language_test//languages/bn` 
and 
`http://localhost/cartpro_language_test/languages/bn`

make sure its accesible in your routes check `php artisan route:list`

by default its accessible under `/languages` not `/cartpro_language_test/languages` so verify if there is any other changes you made that cause the url to be different than the one sat up

i did the exact same modifications and its working for me